# Why Vuejs data is not getting updated in the end of the method?

Tags: vue.js

I have a method in my VueJS code:

```
updateTaskRun : function(task) {
    task.pivot.isLoading = true;
    let updateUrl = `{{url('task-runs')}}/${task.pivot.id}/update`;

    axios.put(updateUrl , {
        is_finished: task.pivot.is_finished
    })
        .then(function(response){
            task.pivot.isLoading = false;
            console.log(task.pivot.id);
        })
},
```

The `isLoading` property is used to disable the checkbox like this:

```
 <input type="checkbox"
       :disabled="task.pivot.isLoading"
       v-on:change="updateTaskRun(task)"
       v-model="task.pivot.is_finished">
```

The problem I am getting is that the `task.pivot.isLoading` is not set to false after the response is retrieven. I have checked that in Vue Devtools. However when I disable another checkbox, the previous one gets its `isLoading` set to false.

Comment: You can use async await, cutch and finally like"updateTaskRun : async function(task) {
    await task.pivot.isLoading = true;
    let updateUrl = `{{url('task-runs')}}/${task.pivot.id}/update`;

    await axios.put(updateUrl , {
        is_finished: task.pivot.is_finished
    })
        .then(function(response){
            task.pivot.isLoading = false;
            console.log(task.pivot.id);
        }).catch(function (error) {
     task.pivot.isLoading = false;
    console.log(error);
  })
  .finally(function () { task.pivot.isLoading = false;
    // always executed
  });
},"

Comment: does the PUT request complete successfully? do you get the `console.log(task.pivot.id)` output ?

Comment: do you run the `<input type="checkbox" :disabled="task.pivot.isLoading" ...` in the `v-for` cycle? does your iteration elementhas `:key` property?

Comment: @birdspider yes it executes correctly and after it the console log shows the correct id

Comment: @AndriyKuba I do run it, but don't use the :key

Comment: Try to add the `:key` property, it can be a reason for the issue: https://css-tricks.com/list-rendering-and-vues-v-for-directive/#article-header-id-2